# Cakephp 2.3.: URL rewrite doesnt work

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

we just moved from one webserver to another.
I have a simple static website, and using this method to rewrite the urls:

default.ctp

```
<?=$this->Html->link(__('Imprint'), array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'imprint'));?>
```

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
Router::connect('/imprint', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'imprint'));
```

On the old webserver the link was shown as: domain.com/imprint

On the new server it shows as domain.com/pages/imprint

The page is working, no broken links at all.
I have set the "RewriteBase /" in the htaccess files.

How can I get the url rewrite back to work?
I have currently no idea what the error could be, as I moved another cake project, also a static one and there the links work great right from the beginning. I have no idea, why this project is different, I compared the htaccess file, the core, the routes... I can't really see the issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how this could be related to the server, and how your URL array matches any of these routes at all.

## Order matters

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration**

Routes are processed from "*top to bottom*", so you have to make sure that specific routes are defiend *before* generic ones.

In your case the `/pages/*` route takes precedence, it swallows every subsequent page route like your `/imprint` one.

So change the order, put `/imprint` before `/pages/*`:

```
Router::connect('/imprint', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'imprint'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

## Reverse routing

The URL array that you are using for generating links doesn't look like it could match any of your routes. It neither specifies the `display` action, nor the page name parameter.

When generating links, use the proper URL array as already shown by @kicaj

```
array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'imprint')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$this->Html->link(__('Imprint'), array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'imprint'));
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. Nothing changed.